# While creating swipe to reveal feature like new whatsapp iOS app, gesture recorgnizers gets mixed with each other

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

Here is the screenshot of new whatsapp's swipe to reveal feature.

[image: Swipe to reveal whatsapp]

In my iOS application, I want to implement similar feature. I have implemented navigation drawer using view controller containment.

Following is the hierarchy of my application

```
MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER
--  VIEW
    --  TABLE VIEW INSTANCE (NAVIGATION DRAWER)
    --  CONTAINER VIEW i.e. UIVIEW INSTANCE (HERE I ATTACHED PAN GESTURE, LETS SAY P1 to swipe left to right to show navigation drawer)
        --  CHILD VIEW CONTROLLERS VIEW AS CONTAINER VIEW'S SUBVIEW
            --  TABLE VIEW TO SHOW LIST OF VIRTUAL MACHINES (ALREADY HAVE GESTURE RECOGNIZER. LETS SAY P2)
                --  TABLE VIEW CELL'S CONTENT VIEW
                    -- MORE BUTTON
                    -- ARCHIEVE BUTTON
                    -- VM DETAIL VIEW (HERE ALSO I ATTACHED PAN GESTURE. LETS SAY P3)
```

PROBLEM:

When APP Starts and I open drawer by swiping from left to right, my drawer opens completely. See below screenshot

[image]

Now when I try to close drawer by swiping from right to left, pan gesture P3 (FROM VM DETAIL VIEW) start interfering with pan gesture P1 (FROM CONTAINER VIEW). This result in opening of hidden options that are behind table view cell. See below screenshot.

[image]

[image]

If anyone having any idea please let me know. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can make the tableview 'unresponsive' by giving the tablecells a state that checks in which state you are in. Another option is to create a transparent overlay view that speicifically intercepts the swipe gesture. What have you tried already?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus - please see the view hierarchy attached. I implemented in that way.

Comment: I was aware of that. The problem with that structure is that the pangesture on your containerview is part of the chain of views with gesturerecognizers on them. You want either P2 and P3 to be skipped when you swipe OR have a view outside of this chain so that P2 and P3 won't get triggered at all. This will be achieved by either giving them a state so that they get skipped when you have done P1 OR have an overlay which will receive the gestures when you have done P1.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus - ok sir. I got what you are trying to explain. If I'm not making mistake then you are suggesting me to skip P2 and P3 when using P1. But how? Can you please explain. you have given me suggestion that "by either giving them a state so that they get skipped", but how to do it actually? Which state you are explaining?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus - If you wan't then I can post my program here

Comment: Please show me how you made your recognizers and how you handle their responses. When P1 happens you should set a flag(boolean). When that flag is active you prevent P2 and P3 from triggering. After you swipe back (left to right), let's call it P4 now, you will unflag it again. Then you can do either P1, P2 or P3.

Comment: Addendum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979702/how-to-block-a-gesture-from-superview-to-subview You might want to take a look at this.